# ZKT eco uFace 800 Machine How i can read inserted data records in C# windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, device, face-recognition, time-and-attendance

i am new in external devices integration currently i am working on ZKT eco uFace 800 Machine. I have SDK for it and some of its function like zkfp2.GetDeviceCount() // to get count of connected devices
zkfp2.DBInit()         // to initiate databas
But i dont know how to get full list of record registered in device?? and how to get last inserted or attendance marked record from it? This device is using internal database of Access.
Actuality i want to build a windows service which read data from it and push to SQL external database. Any one who already worked on it please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explore the things and now i have done. I just need to use latest SDK from this link [Here](https://www.zkteco.com/en/index/Service/load/id/674.html)

Here i have all what i need read its documents and install SDK provided in this link and you will be on your track. Thanks

Comment: Sorry this link is not working.